# Greek symbols are all bold in MM 10 over Linux

Tags: front-end, formatting

I upgraded recently to Mathematica 10, on a Linux system, and I'm quite annoyed to find that all the greek symbols automatically show up in bold:

[image]

I suspect the issue is some missing font somewhere so I'm hoping this has some form of quick-ish fix. I am running Mathematica 10.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, so I suspect that this also happens to a fairly broad sector of people (I know of at least one other Ubuntu/MM10 machine with the same issue). Has anyone else encountered this, or can someone think of a quick fix?